# How can I merge a list into a dataframe?

Tags: python, list, merge

I have the following dataframe and list:

```
df = [[[1,2,3],'a'],[[4,5],'b'],[[6,7,8],'c']]
list = [[1,2,3],[4,5]]
```

And I want to do a inner merge between them, so I can keep the items in common. This will be my result:

```
df = [[1,2,3],'a'],[[4,5],'b']]
```

I have been thinking in converting both to strings, but even if I convert my list to string, I haven't been able to merge both of them as the merge function requires the items to be series or dataframes (not strings). This could be a great help!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want only keep rows from the dataframe where the values (lists) are both in the column and the list:

```py
lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
print(df[df["col1"].isin(lst)])
```

Prints:

```
        col1 col2
0  [1, 2, 3]    a
1     [4, 5]    b
```

---

DataFrame used:

```
        col1 col2
0  [1, 2, 3]    a
1     [4, 5]    b
2  [6, 7, 8]    c
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer!

This is what worked for me:

1. Convert my list to a series (my using DB):

> match = pd.Series(','.join(map(str,match)))

2. Convert the list of my master DB into a string:

> df_temp2['match_s'].loc[m] =
> ','.join(map(str,df_temp2['match'].loc[m]))

3. Applied an inner merge on both DB:

> df_temp3 = df_temp2.merge(match.rename('match'), how='inner',
> left_on='match_s', right_on='match')

Hope it also works for somebody else :)